# Correct Configuration for Route 53 -> ALB HTTPS -> Target Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

Background:

- 2 domains with Route53
- 1 ALB
- 1 Target group with 2 EC2

Goal:
[www.domain123.com](http://www.domain123.com) always goes -> https://www.domain123.com

If a user types in domain123.com (without www) it should also go to https://www.domain123.com

1. First question, is this correct / appropriate DNS configuration?

Current set up -
Route53:

- domain123.com  A record -> LoadBalancer
- domain123.com  NS
- domain123.com  SOA

2. Second question, do I need a CNAME here?  I have seen mixed videos of people doing this and not doing this.

Application load balancer set up -
Listeners:

- HTTPS Port 443 -> Forward to Target Group
- Default ACM (SSL) certificate

3. Third question, do I need another listener on Port 80?

Target Group -

- 2 EC2 instances listening on Port 80

4. Fourth question, I want to host a couple sites.  Does the ServerName and ServerAlias need to contain the www?

Conf file -
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain123.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain123.com"
ServerName domain123.com
#ServerAlias domain123.com
ErrorLog "logs/domain123.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/domain123.com-access_log" common

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question as you're using Route 53 its better to use an [Alias record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) (via the A record type), this will resolve your hostname directly to the IP addresses of he load balancer. Ensure you have a record for each domain that needs to resolve to the load balancer.

For your second question, you don't need to use a `CNAME` you can use an Alias record to resolve either directly to the load balancer or another Route 53 record that you have access to.

For your third question you don't need a listener on port 80, but you must if you want to do a HTTP to HTTPS redirect. As its target you can actually add a redirect action to have it redirect to HTTPS, therefor

For your fourth question if the hostname is not matched in another Vhost the first VirtualHost will serve the traffic.

If you want to always go to `www.example.com` you should do the following in your ALB.

- For the HTTP listener add a redirect rule for the default action that will redirect to the HTTPS first of `www.example.com` with the path appended.
- For the HTTPS listener add a host header based rule that will forward traffic to your target group if the domain is `www.example.com`, then for the default actions have it redirect to the `www.example.com` domain as it is not on it.

Take a look at these links:

- [Host-Based Routing Support for AWS Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)
- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)
- [Listener rules for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html)

Comment: Thanks Chris!  So, if I follow you correctly.  There should be two A records for both www.domain123.com and domain123.com ?  With both going to the ALB.

Comment: Yes, making sure to use them as Alias records :)

Comment: Thanks Chris I got those Alias records updated.  Trying to wrap my head around the last piece and the ALB set up.  Is what I am doing standard practice?  I want to make sure I am doing this correctly.  I am going to have a few domains here so I assume I will have to X the changes for each?

Comment: The recommendations are standard practice, effectively moving the redirects to the ALB means that your server is not having to deal with the redirects and instead can just serve the application :)

Comment: Thanks again Chris.  So after reading through one of the articles.  Here is my attempt at your first suggestion for HTTP:  THEN
Redirect to https://www .#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_301

Comment: That would work although if you always want to redirect to the www domain you could also rather than using `#{host}` specify the hostname to redirect to. This way it goes from 2 redirects to 1 redirect. I would also suggest using a 302 first to test, 301 is permanent so if configured wrong could be hard to fix :)

Comment: Ah you modified the comment, yes looks great now. But take a look at 302 vs 301 :)

Comment: Thanks again.  Changing to a 302 and testing this a bunch.  Then once live ill switch it to a 301.

Comment: Sure, glad this helped you. Have a great day :D